# WCF secured request with unsecured response

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a binding in WCF which can sign the body in the request with a certificate but reply with an unsecured response? I can't find that configuration/binding anywhere.

Alternatively, is there a way to remove the Security header from the response? It seems the Security header is added to the envelope AFTER it has gone through the IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply method, so I can't even manipulate the soap message XML before it is sent back to the client.

Comment: Yes, this can be done.  I did this recently using a custom binding to send a signed request to a Java web service, which returned an unsigned response.   Can you provide some more context around the requirement?   Are you talking about the client or the service?

Comment: In my case I am writing the actual service, not the client. The client has to send a secured request and receive an unsecured response (eg absolutely no Security header at all). This asymmetric contract is a bit odd and not really in line with WCF in general, but that's what they want.